# Simulating an apply() for constructors (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, constructor, bind, apply

I'm new to JavaScript and currently I am reading Rausch's book "Speaking JavaScript", where I came across following notation under the "Simulating apply() for constructors" section:

```
new (Date.bind(null, 2011, 11, 24))
```

Now this seems pretty confusing to me. Can someone explain this statement in details? In particular, I can't get the meaning of the parenthesis that come after the 'new' keyword, plus, as far as I'm concerned, 'bind' is a method that can be applied only to functions, isn't it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The global `Date` constructor *is* a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date.bind(null, 2011, 11, 24)
```

returns a function that invokes the global `Date` function with those three numeric parameters (Christmas eve 2011). The `new` operator can be applied to any function, so in this case it's being applied to that one. Consider this rewrite:

```
var ChristmasEve2011 = Date.bind(null, 2011, 11, 24);
var d = new ChristmasEve2011();
```

The parentheses are necessary because of the operator precedence of `new`. Without the parentheses, the parser would interpret that as a call via `new` of the `Date.bind` function. *With* the parentheses, the `bind` call happens *first*, followed by the `new` call to the returned function.

Note that because of the nature of functions created by `.bind()`, the use of the `new` operator doesn't make a lot of sense. When the `Date` constructor is actually called, the value of `this` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

'.bind' returns a new function with the value of this bind to the first argument passed to the function.
In this case the value of 'this' will be 'null'.
So it just returns the Date constructor without anything particular.

It's similar to:

```
new Date(2011, 11, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [site](http://www.2ality.com/2011/08/spreading.html) at point 3. It will go into some detail about it.